# Reporting of workflow and times

Tags: t-sql, data-warehouse

I have to start moving transnational data into a reporting database, but would like to move towards a more warehouse/data mart design, eventually leveraging Sql Server Analytics.

The thing that is being measured is the time between points of a workflow on a piece of work.  How would you model that when the things that can happen, do not have a specific order.  Also some work wont have all the actions, or might have the same action multiple times.

It makes me want to put the data into a typical relational design with one table the key or piece of work and a table that has all the actions and times.  Is that wrong?  The business is going to try to use tableau for report writing and I know it can do all kinds of sources, but again, I would like to move away from transaction into warehousing.

The work is the dimension and the actions and times are the facts?

Is there any other good online resources for modeling questions?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide more detail? What data do you have? What kind of reports do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may seem like splitting hairs, but you don't want to measure the time between points in a workflow, you need to measure time within a point of a workflow.  If you change your perspective, it can become much easier to model.

Your OLTP system will likely capture the timestamp of when the event occurred.  When you convert that to OLAP, you should turn that into a start & stop time for each event.  While you're at it, calculate the duration, in seconds or minutes, and the occurrence number for the event.  If the task was sent to "Design" three times, you should have three design events, numbered 1,2,3.

If you're want to know how much time a task spent in design, the cube will sum the duration of all three design events to present a total time.  You can also do some calculated measures to determine first time in and last time out.

Having the start & stop times of the task allow you to , for example, find all of tasks that finished design in January.

If you're looking for an average above the event grain, for example what is the average time in design across all tasks, you'll need to do a new calculated measure using total time in design/# tasks (not events).

Assuming you have more granular states, it is a good idea to define parent states for use in executive reporting.  In my company, the operational teams have workflows with 60+ states, but management wanted them rolled up into five summary states.  The rollup hierarchy should be part of your workflow states dimension.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you.  I will model it out and see.